# How to hide the labels of the formulas in the final output pdf?

Tags: tables, margins, text-manipulation

[image]I want to hide the labels of the math formulas and equations in the output pdf, what is related command to do that? (see the picture)

The followings are the packages I use in my \documentclass[12pt]{article}

```
\usepackage[T1,T5]{fontenc}

\usepackage{colordvi,cite,comment,color}
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
\usepackage{subfigure}

\usepackage{amsbsy,amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,amsxtra}

\usepackage{epsfig,fancyhdr,latexsym}

\usepackage[stable]{footmisc}

\usepackage{amscd}

\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{indentfirst}

\usepackage{verbatim}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{showlabels}

\usepackage{cite}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{cancel}

\usepackage{todonotes}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, urlcolor=black}

\hypersetup{citecolor=black}

\usepackage[subfigure]{tocloft}

\usepackage{sectsty}

\allsectionsfont{\normalsize\raggedright}
```

[image]

Comment: Hint: you're loading a package called `showlabels` ..

Comment: as well as not loading showlabels do not use epsfig

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thanks

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That  "showlabels" lonely did the job

Comment: yes sure epsfig is unrelated but shouldn't be used in any document written this century.